# I'm looking for a reporting tool similar to Crystal Reports but free that integrates well with React

Tags: reporting, react

I'm looking for a reporting tool that meets the following criteria:

- Integration with React
- REST API support
- Chart and graph capabilities
- Filtering capabilities
- Must have drag and drop designer
- Must have report generator designer environment similar to Crystal Reports
- Performance optimization
- Documentation and community support
- Compatibility with Linux
- Support for PostgreSQL and other databases
- Open-source availability
- Preferably free or very affordable
- Ability to receive properties from React application
- Report export functionality
- Cloud-based availability (optional)
- Ability to Create Tabular Reports: Good support for creating tabular reports.

Power BI and Tableau are too expensive. Are there any other tools that you recommend?